# Articles renamed auto draft after saving on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My problem is when I make an article and save it, whatever I fill in, the title goes into auto draft and all the content is not saved. So I did some tests and it doesn't come from my theme or plugin and not from my code because I have nothing consistent with this. Could this come from the Wordpress core or the database? Do you have any ideas for this etc? I also did some tests with removing wp_post from my database and taking the table from my locale which creates a post actually works but the problem is still there.

Im on Wordpress last version, using my theme with twig, barbajs ... But this is the first time i have this problem on a project.

I except some idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . As you're new, please take the [tour] and read [ask] too, to understand how to get the best out of Stackoverflow.